# Удаленная работа в облаке на OSX?

Tags: macos

Нужно кодить под OSX, рассматриваю варианты покупки мака или аренду облака. Вот хотел совета по поводу работы в облаке.

Меня смущает что все что я нашел это в штатах, а я во Владивостоке. Пинг чисто физически не может быть меньше 200мс. Канал то еще пол беды, но вот главный вопрос - не налагает ли каких-то ограничений удаленка? Я имею ввиду например rdp юзер на винде имеет ограничения, а на маках как оно?